# Why do I get 'detail: not found' for primary key formatted as '12-345.78'?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

When I try to display detail info calling e.g. `/api/products/12-345.67/`, I get `detail: Not found.` as a response. As you can see, product IDs are formatted as `12-345.67`. My first suspect was the RegEx validator (listed below), but it works the same way with or without it.

Model, serializers, viewsets and URLs are defined this way:

```py
# models.py:
class Product(models.Model):
   product_id = models.CharField(max_length=9, primary_key=True)
   name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.product_id

# serializers.py:
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   product_id = serializers.RegexField(regex='^\d{2}-\d{3}\.\d{2}$', max_length=9, min_length=9, allow_blank=False)
   name = serializers.CharField(min_length=6, max_length=50, allow_blank=False)

   class Meta:
      model = Product
      fields = '__all__'

class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
   queryset = Product.objects.all()
   serializer_class = ProductSerializer
   lookup_field = 'product_id'

# urls.py:
router = routers.DefaultRouter()

router.register(r'products', ProductViewSet, basename='products')
(...)

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    (...)
```

Comment: I don't think you should be having full stops (`.`) in you API endpoints.

Comment: @ToniSredanović: indeed... Please post it as the answer & hvala ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you should be having full stops (`.`) in you API endpoints. Probably change the `id` to something else. & Zapraszamy :D